# Unsorted list won't display two columns in media query

Tags: html, css

I have a list that is displayed in two columns on my page.

I want the list to be displayed the same way in my media query for print.

```css
#tc {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tc">
  <li class="lft"><input type="checkbox"><label>Interna/eksterna provera</label></li>
  <li class="lft"><input type="checkbox"><label>Reklamacije/Žalbe</label></li>
  <li class="lft"><input type="checkbox"><label>Prijemna kontrola</label></li>
  <li class="lft"><input type="checkbox"><label>Greške u toku procesa rada</label></li>
  <li class="lft"><input type="checkbox"><label>Ostalo</label></li>
  <li><label>Datum:</label><input type="date"></li>
  <li><label>Datum:</label><input type="date"></li>
  <li><label>Datum:</label><input type="date"></li>
  <li><label>Datum:</label><input type="date"></li>
  <li><label>Datum:</label><input type="date"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here like below */

    #tc {
         columns: 2;
         -webkit-columns: 2;
         -moz-columns: 2;
   } 
}
```